# What does !! do in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Authorization code example

```
    const refreshTokens = await db.RefreshToken.find({ user: user.id });
    req.user.ownsToken = token => !!refreshTokens.find(x => x.token === token);
    next();
```

What does !! actually, do?

Comment: Checks if the value is truthy or falsy. https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: In this case it would make more sense to use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of [`.find()`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: @AnaSvitlica Which values are compared in this example?

Comment: In your example it checks if the result of `.find()` function is a falsy value (`null, undefined, 0, '', "", false, NaN`). So !! will give you false if the value of `.find()` is falsy.

Comment: You can open console in your browser and type something like `!![]` or `!!null` if you're unsure what it returns for certain values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Any value can be converted to a real Boolean value using a double-negative**

!! to be absolutely certain a false is generated only by false, 0, "", null, undefined and NaN:

```
// instead of
if (x === y) // ...
// runs if x and y are identical...
// except when both are NaN

// use
if (!!x === !!y) // ...
// runs if x and y are identical...
// including when either or both are NaN
```